# MySQL insert on duplicate key; delete?

Tags: mysql, key, duplicates, sql-delete

Is there a way of removing record on duplicate key in MySQL?

Say we have a record in the database with the specific primary key and we try to add another one with the same key - `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` would simply update the record, but is there an option to remove record if already exists? It is for simple in/out functionality on click of a button.

Comment: Thanks - I think that's the only option.

Answer (score 12):

It's a work-around, but it works:

Create a new column and call it `do_delete`, or whatever, making it a tiny-int.  Then do `On Duplicate Key Update do_delete = 1;`

Depending on your MySQL version/connection, you can execute multiple queries in the same statement.  However, if not, just run a separate query immediately afterwords.  Either way, the next query would just be: `Delete From [table] Where do_delete = 1;`.  This way, if its a new entry, it will not delete anything.  If it was not a new entry, it will then mark it for deletion then you can delete it.

Comment: I like this option - and will not need to change my update statement.

Comment: Brilliant solution! Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Use [REPLACE INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html):

```
replace into some_table
select somecolumn from othertable
```

will either insert new data or if thr same data exist will delete the data and insert the new one

Comment: The performance of replace into vs ON DUPLICATE UPDATE, are different. REPLACE INTO is not updating the record - it delete the record and add it again, if you have tons of data and indexes involved, it can take a while ... better to use ON DUPLICATE UPDATE, but he's asking to REMOVE something like ON DUPLICATE DELETE

Answer (score 3):

The nearest possible solution for the same is **`REPLACE`** statement. Here is the [documentation for REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html).

A similar question was asked on [MySQL Forums](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,203800,203800#msg-203800) and the [recommended(and only) answer](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,203800,203975#msg-203975) was to use **`REPLACE`**.

Comment: Yes, but that's not quite what I'm looking for - I don't want to replace the item in the database - if it exists I want to get rid of it all together.

Comment: I guess the only option (if the above is the only possible solution) in that case will be to run separate statements - first to check if record is found then based on the result either add it or remove it.

Comment: or create a `BOOLEAN` or `ENUM` column and set it 0 or 1, depending on you want it or not.

Answer (score 0):

to be more clear with mySql:
values can be from same table:
`replace into table1 (column1,column2) select (val1,val2) from table1`

or
values can be from another table:
`replace into table1 (column1,column2) select (val1,val2) from table2`

or
values can be from any table with condition:
`replace into table1 (column1,column2) select (val1,val2) from table1  where <br>column3=val3 and column4=val4 ...`

or
also remember values can be static with table name for namesake:
`replace into table1 (column1,column2) select (123,"xyz") from table1`

no error will be thrown even if the update results in duplicate entry, as it will be replaced.
**(remember) only autoincrement value will be increased;**

and
**if you have column with data-type "TIMESTAMP" with "on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", it will have no effect;**

Answer (score -2):

Yes of course there is a solutions in MySQL for your problem.

If you want to delete or skip the new inserting record if there already a duplicate record exists in the key column of the table, you can use IGNORE like this:

```
insert ignore into mytbl(id,name) values(6,'ron'),(7,'son');
```

Here `id` column is primary key in the table `mytbl`. This will insert multiple values in the table by deleting or skipping the new duplicate records.

Hope this will fulfill your requirement.

Comment: insert ignore does NOT delete anything