# SQL UPDATE or DELETE if duplicate

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run 3 queries in my database :

```
UPDATE `table` SET `rubriq` = '77' WHERE `rubriq` = '61';
UPDATE `table` SET `rubriq` = '77' WHERE `rubriq` = '62';
UPDATE `table` SET `rubriq` = '77' WHERE `rubriq` = '63';
```

In `table` i have two columns `abonne` and `rubriq`. Abonne is primary key, and two are index.

If in my database I have for example :

```
 abonne  | rubriq  
  84     |   61  
  84     |   62 
  84     |   63
```

When I run my 3 queries, for the first there is no problem but for the second, i have an error : `#1062 - Duplicate entry '84-77' for key 1`

How can i do for run these 3 queries but, when there is an error like that, just remove the line ?

Thanks !

Comment: maybe your `rubriq` column is primary key. please check. and also, you just only have 1 column in your rubriq?

Comment: Please provide the structure of the tables and its keys. Please also check the unique indexes.

Comment: Your table consist unique key with the column `abonne` and `rubriq` which is showing error for the `Duplicate Entry`

Comment: abonne is primary key, and two columns are index

Comment: When you say "*just remove the line*", do you mean that you want to remove the duplicate records from the table or that you want to remove the command from the execution list?  If the former, are we correct in presuming that the first record to hold the conflicting values is to be preserved and all others are to be deleted?  If the latter, are we correct in presuming that the command should still execute for all other (non-conflicting) records?

Comment: Are the indexes unique?

Comment: In my example, i need to remove 84-62 and 84-63

Comment: Use directive `ON DUPLICATE KEY` or see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11495090/5043424)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to manually delete the records that will cause a conflict:

```
UPDATE `table` SET rubriq = 77 WHERE rubriq = 61;

DELETE t62
FROM   `table` t77
  JOIN `table` t62 USING (abonne)
WHERE  t77.rubriq = 77
   AND t62.rubriq = 62;

UPDATE `table` SET rubriq = 77 WHERE rubriq = 62;

DELETE t63
FROM   `table` t77
  JOIN `table` t63 USING (abonne)
WHERE  t77.rubriq = 77
   AND t63.rubriq = 63;

UPDATE `table` SET rubriq = 77 WHERE rubriq = 63;
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be the same thing as what eggyal is doing, but their version is too complicated for me to understand. This is what I did in a similar situation.

```sql
UPDATE OR IGNORE table SET rubriq = 77 WHERE rubriq = 61;
DELETE FROM table WHERE rubriq = 61;

UPDATE OR IGNORE table SET rubriq = 77 WHERE rubriq = 62;
DELETE FROM table WHERE rubriq = 62;

UPDATE OR IGNORE table SET rubriq = 77 WHERE rubriq = 63;
DELETE FROM table WHERE rubriq = 63;
```

Basically, if a duplicate exists, ignore it. Then after the updates, delete any rows that are left over.